# Problem with filestream path in C++ when copying files

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, filestream

Brace with me here. I'm trying to make a few simple, but useful C++ console apps that I want to run by starting them straight from cmd (like DiskPart for example). I have a finished product, compiled by gcc through VS Code powershell. The idea is: I have a main.exe and a data file stored in "veco/data.txt" next to the executable. The code works perfectly well when started from its folder where it was compiled, but when I try to copy it to WindowsApps folder (to be able to start it by typing its name in cmd) it just doesn't work...
Yes I did copy the folder too, I've tried to run it from powershell and I get 0 crash msgs...

Here's the part where I interact with the text file:

```
  string s = _pathToExe + "veco\\data.txt";
  ifstream is(s);
  //i do stuff here
  is.close();
```

where **_pathToExe** is path to the executable, without the actual name of the executable. **ifstream is(s)** seems to be the crashing point.

I compiled the code using two commands:

```
g++ -c <all .cpps>
g++ -o main.exe <all objs>
```

Can I make this work somehow? Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Note: I've tried copying to other locations, doesn't work there either.

Comment: ***WindowsApps folder (to be able to start it by typing its name in cmd) it just doesn't work.*** That is because the OS prevents you from writing to that location. Your process needs elevation to write to one of the system protected folders.

Comment: As I said, I tried using other paths, just to see if elevation is the problem, it doesn't work there either.

Comment: have you  tried to use relative path(./veco/data.txt)?

Comment: Yeah... Doesn't work